# Connecting to database via php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-connection

I've simply trying to connect to the database but unfortunately it doesn't do it at all. I've got scripts at the bottom that it's pointing to first so just wondering if there's anything a bit strange.

I done some research and found out that the php method I've written is a bit old and considering I used the same last year and it worked.

Anything that makes it obvious it doesn't connect let me know.

Thanks.

connect.php:

```
<?php
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection problems.';
mysql_connect('localhost', 'devdegre_ddevlin', 'password123') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('devdegre_logreg') or die($connect_error);
?>
```

init.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

$current_file = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$current_file = end($current_file);

if (logged_in() === true) {
$session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password',  
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password_recover', 'type',

'allow_email', 'profile');
if (user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
if ($current_file !== 'changepassword.php' && $user_data['password_recover'] == 1) {
    header('Location: changepassword.php?force');
    exit();
}
}

$errors = array();
?>
```

I've dumped sql to create a user database and entered a user. It always goes to the connect.php so I can't work it out I've tried various ways to connect with username, password etc.

Comment: don't use mysql.it is deprecated

Comment: You haven't shown your `user_data()` function, so we can't help you.

Comment: You probably should google 'OOP programming' as well...

Answer (score 0):

Since `mysql` and its other components are depreciated due to security issues and performance, here is the usage of the `mysqli` class :

```
<?php
    /* database connection information */
    $server = ""; 
    $user = ""; 
    $password = "";
    $database = "";

    /* query */
    $query = "
        SELECT id 
        FROM whatever
    ";

    /* error messages */
    $messErr_connectionDatabaseFailed = "Error : connection failed. Please try later.";

    $link = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);

    /* If connection failed */
    if (!$link) {
        printf($messErr_connectionDatabaseFailed);
        printf("<br />");
    }
    /* If connection successed */
    else {
        $resultQuery = $link->query($query);

        /* find around mysqli::fetch_assoc() function to display result */
    }
?>
```

Query part is optional.